# JQuery Week Calendar: CSS to control header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find the CSS in the jquery.weekcalendar.css file that controls the size of the text in the header, i.e. June 17, 2013 - June 21, 2013.

I have to squeeze my calendar into a small space and so I'd like to change the font size of this code (and remove the 2013).

Thanks for any helpful tips!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bBwW/ (still looking to get jquery week calendar css/js files as CDN).

Here's my calendar init code:

```
$('#week-calendar').weekCalendar({
                          firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                          daysToShow: 5,
                          useShortDayNames: true,
                          showHeader: true,
                          timeslotsPerHour: 4,
                          scrollToHourMillis: 0,
                          businessHours:{start: 8, end: 18, limitDisplay: false },
                          height: function(data){
                            return $(window).height() - $('h1').outerHeight(true);
                          },
                          data: eventData,
                          eventRender : function( calEvent, $event ) {
                                if( calEvent.end.getTime() < new Date().getTime() ) {
                                    $event.css( "backgroundColor", "#aaa" );
                                    $event.css( "font-size", "1" );
                                    $event.find( ".time" ).css( {"backgroundColor": "#999", "border":"1px solid #888" } );
                                }
                            },
                          eventClick : function( calEvent, $event ) {
                              window.location.href = 'lobby?meetingId='+calEvent.id;
                            },
                        });
```

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Comment: put your code in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks, just did. Trying to get plugin css/js files to add there but not sure if they're available as CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
.wc-title
```

It's in jquery-weekcalendar.css and there is no font-size set.